# Updating Parameters SSRS/RB3

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012, subscription, reportbuilder3.0

I am very new to making automated reports with SSRS(2012)/RB3. However what I have managed to do so far is take my already existing code place it in RB3 to make a report upload it to SSRS and set up subscriptions.

However, at this point I need to add more options to a parameter in  an existing report. I made the changes in the RB3 and saved that file. This change did not go through to SSRS. I am assuming I have to re-upload the report replacing the previous one.

I just wanted to know before I do that if that means I will have to delete and remake my current subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** - it will not automatically delete your old subscriptions when you re-deploy a report over the existing one (that would suck if it did).

Of course your report may not generate if there's a **new parameter** without a **default** value that the subscription doesn't populate.

I tried to find a source in MSDN but couldn't find anything that said that. The closest was an answered question.

[Redeploy Reports](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3198e1d4-d715-42e5-ae69-8d2406ab9603/redeploy-reports?forum=sqlreportingservices)